# message to the user after the first login

Tags: linux, shell-script, accounts

is there any way to display a message to the user just after the *first* login?

I want to show him that "this is the first time that you are logging with this account".

Answer (score 13):

When you create the account, create a file named `~/.not_logged_in_yet`. It doesn't have to have any contents, the file just needs to exist:

```
touch ~user/.not_logged_in_yet        # create the file
chown user ~user/.not_logged_in_yet   # should be owned by the user
chmod u+rw ~user/.not_logged_in_yet   # user must be able to delete it
```

Then, create a script named `/etc/profile.d/check_first_login.sh` that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
# only do this for interactive shells
if [ "$-" != "${-#*i}" ]; then
    if [ -f "$HOME/.not_logged_in_yet" ]; then
        echo "Welcome, this is your first login"
        rm "$HOME/.not_logged_in_yet"
    fi
fi
```

When you login with bash as your shell, the shell will source `/etc/profile` (see [Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the manual). `/etc/profile` sources all `*.sh` files in `/etc/profile.d/`, so adding a file in there make it visible for all users on your machine.

You only want to print that message if the session is **interactive**. Printing anything from your profile can break things that are supposed to non-interactive (such as `ssh-copy-id` -- although I don't know if that specifically breaks). The bash variable `$-` contains some of the settings set with the `set` command:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $-; set -ex; echo $-'
hBc
+ echo ehxBc
ehxBc
```

This form of parameter expansion `${-#*i}` removes a leading substring ending with an "i". `$-` will only contain an "i" if it's an interactive bash session, so `"$-"` will only be not equal to `"${i#*i}"` if the session is interactive. There are other ways to test this: see [Is this shell interactive?](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) -- I used this method because that's what /etc/profile does.

Comment: Glenn, could you please explain the first "if" of your script?

Comment: Actually, could you just explain the whole thing?

Comment: The first `if` statement ensures that the stanza only fires if it's an interactive shell (`$-` contains the letter `i`). The second checks for the existence of the marker file which indicates an account that hasn't yet logged in with an interactive shell.

Comment: File in `/etc/profile.d`, at least on Debian derivatives are sourced by POSIX-like shells, (not necessarily `bash`), not executed. So the `#!/bin/bash` is irrelevant here. And the syntax has to be POSIX compliant (which is the case in your case). Using `case $- in *i*)` would make it more legible.

Comment: Note that the test for $- doesn't work in the Bourne shell (I wouldn't concern myself too much with that), and the test for PS1 (as referenced in the link you gave) is bash-specific (it's the only shell to clear it from the environment when non-interactive, `yash` sets it even when non-interactive)

Comment: Great answer and nice explanation. In addition I would suggest creating the `.not_logged_in_yet` file in `/etc/skel` so that `useradd` copies it over automatically.